# Checking to see if a number ends in 5?

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a function that takes 2 parameters, adds them up, and if the sum of the two parameters ends in 5, it reports a 2. If it doesn't end in 5, it returns 8.

Any ideas?

I was thinking of doing an if statement, but I'm confused as to how I would check if a number ends in 5( or is 5).

Thanks for your help, trying to teach myself how to program is so difficult yet so rewarding :)

Answer (score 12):

### Solution

My answer assumes you are checking integers (which seems pretty reasonable judging from your question):

```py
def sum_ends_with_5(a, b):
    """
    Checks if sum ends with "5" digit.
    """
    result = a + b
    return 2 if result % 10 == 5 else 8
```

or more flexible (with any number of arguments):

```py
def sum_ends_with_5(*args):
    """
    Checks if sum ends with "5" digit.
    """
    result = sum(args)
    return 2 if result % 10 == 5 else 8
```

### How it works (aka tests)

The function behaves like that:

```py
>>> sum_ends_with_5(5)
2
>>> sum_ends_with_5(3)
8
>>> sum_ends_with_5(2, 8)
8
>>> sum_ends_with_5(7, 8)
2
>>> sum_ends_with_5(10, 20, 3, 2)
2
```

### Shorter version

So, if you want to write it in shorter and more flexible way, you can do this:

```py
def sum_ends_with_5(*args):
    return 2 if sum(args) % 10 == 5 else 8
```

Comment: +1 for the varargs feature alone. Not enamoured with the function name (sounds like it should return a boolean value) but that's a minor nitpick.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks. The function name is really hard part, as I am not sure what is the purpose of such function ;) But it works as OP wanted, I suppose.

Comment: +1 Definitely the most thorough of a sea of answers!  (Confound it! :))

Comment: +1 I agree, very thorough and nice (I like it better than my own answer :)

Comment: I don't know what `How it works` is about, since it doesn't even try to explain anything... Anyway, as for the name: I'd remove the `2 else 8` part from the function and just call the function instead: `2 if sum_ends_with_5(args) else 8` that's more readable.

Comment: @phant0m: That is why it was called "_How it works (aka tests)_" (note "_(aka tests)_" part). There is not much to explain, it just _shows_ how it works, does not _explain_ it. I agree `sum_ends_with_5` is not the best name for what this function does, but it is hard to figure out the better name, sorry. It is all placed in one function, because OP explicitly said he is "_trying to define a function that..._".

Comment: I see what you did there, it just looks better I guess :P `OP explicitly said he is "trying to define a function that..."` In that case, I'd just overrule that decision if I found an alternative to be arguably better and explain why I did so.

Comment: @phant0m: Yes, I understand ;) Actually the solution would look best without any function (just `2 if (a + b) % 10 == 5 else 8`) as it is fairly simple and more readable than function, requires less lines and does not have overhead of function.

Answer (score 5):

Take the modulus by 10 and check if it's 5.

```
print num % 10 == 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Numbers end in 5 if and only if they are are divisible by 5 but are not divisible by 10.  You can easily check for these conditions with modulo arithmetic.  More generally, you can check if a number ends with a digit by comparing the `mod 10` value of that number to the digit.

```
num = 1234
isDivisibleByFive = num % 10 == 5
```

Comment: Can be shortened by just modulus-ing with 10, then you get any remainder from 1 - 9.

Comment: @birryree, I think you may have meant `0 - 9`, yes? :-)

Answer (score 2):

One easy approach is to take the number and convert it to a string and check the last digit using indexing to see if it is 5:

E.g.,

```
n = 153
str(n)[-1] == '5':
False
```

and

```
n = 155
str(155)[-1] == '5'
True
```

So as part of an `if`-statement:

```
if str(n)[-1] == `5`: 
   print "number ends in 5" 
else: 
   print "number did not end in 5"
```

If you just wanted to check for divisibility by 5 (which is different than ending with 5) you could use the mod operation.

But you also could mod by 10 and check for a remainder of 5 to determine if the number (int) ends with 5. My solution checks for the last digit of any number (including floats)

Comment: Thanks Levon! You helped me out yesterday too, the for loop worked out!

Comment: would this work in an if statement? And yeah I did get it working :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this will also report `True` for numbers like 3.1415 and 1.0e+5.

Comment: @Gabe good point .. that's why my answer said it checks the last *digit*, but it bears repeating - thanks.

Comment: Levon do you think I can private message you if I have simple questions about programming instead of making a new thread every time? Is there a pming option on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @BillyThompson I don't know about PMing on SO, but it is better to just post your questions as they come up. This way, anyone who sees it can help, and your wait will be minimal (which is how SO works best)

Comment: While the accepted answer using modulus is perfectly fine, I feel like this is the better answer because it answer's OP's question just as well and is directly generalizable to others.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution from Tadeck best but there is another way, not as good in my opinion for this specific use case, but still may be useful if your return values ever need to follow more complex rules than is available from a simple modulo operation.

```
def xlatVal (*nums):
    #            0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    lookupTbl = [8,8,8,8,8,2,8,8,8,8]
    return lookupTbl[sum(nums) % 10]
```

While the values are still reduced to a range using modulo, this allows arbitrary translations across that range.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a string and check the last character:

```
str(num)[-1] == "5"
```

Comment: I just tried this and i reports an error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: @Billy, not sure what you're doing wrong there: `num = 12345` followed by `print str(num)[-1]` prints out `5` just fine.